# Dead hard drive magically back to life, how's that possible?

Tags: hard-drive

Yesterday I turned on my pc and it could not detect the sata HD, so I unplugged it, plugged to another port on the MOBO, nothing, tried another cable, nothing, it didn't even show up in the BIOS. Tried it on another machine, same results.

I took it back to where I bought the PC, they said they would have tested it and call me back. Today they called me and told me that the drive was working as expected, they had done nothing. Now I've plugged it back in my pc and it's working... All the data is there and is not corrupted or anything.

Any idea on how was that possible? Should I assume that the drive cannot be trusted and change it anyway?

Comment: Back up the data and discard the drive ASAP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adam is right.  Backup and replace as soon as you can.  But as for your question, some more details might help, but there's a lot of room for speculation here.  Just one possibility, though: you mention it's an HDD, so if the internal disk stopped spinning as it should due to some obstacle or jam of sorts, or problem with the drive reader, just the act of transporting the drive may have done something to make a component unstuck, or otherwise resolve whatever was wrong (at least temporarily).  But even in that event, I'd be highly suspicious of a drive that developed a problem like that in the first place.  Backup and replace.

Answer (score 2):

Like gluonman said, we can only speculate.  One possibility might be a break in connectivity with one or more of the circuits on the controller board.  Thermal expansion and contraction *could* theoretically cause the circuit to break and reconnect intermittently.  Like the others have also said, I would back up that data immediately and get a new drive.